# I want to sort given column in ascending and descending as per month and year not alphabetically

Tags: sql-server

```
 monthtext    <-----(column Name in varchar)

'2016july'            
'2016september'       
'2016december'        
'2016january'        
'2017february'       
'2017june'
'2017march'
```

i want to sort it out by ascending or descending not in alphabetical order.
it should has to consider month and year for sorting

for ascending  answer should be like

```
'2016 january'
'2016 july'
'2016 saptember'
'2016 december'
'2017 february'
'2017 march'
'2017 june'
```

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: I am working on sql-server, i need in sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this if all the dates are valid:

```
SELECT monthtext
FROM
  (values
    ('2016july'),('2016september'),('2016december'),('2016january'),
    ('2017february'),('2017june'),('2017march')) x(monthtext)
ORDER BY cast(monthtext as date)
```

Comment: Thank u sir  @ShakeerMirza Its working fine ans its easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

You should add another months also in `case` statement

```
select t.*  from (
    select '2016july' as str union all 
    select '2016september' union all 
    select '2016december' union all 
    select '2016january' union all 
    select '2017february' union all 
    select '2017june' union all 
    select '2017march' 
)t
order by 
    cast( substring(str, 1, 4) as int), 
    case  
        when substring(str, 5, len(str)) = 'january' then 1
        when substring(str, 5, len(str)) = 'february' then 2 
        when substring(str, 5, len(str)) = 'march' then 3
        when substring(str, 5, len(str)) = 'june' then 6
        when substring(str, 5, len(str)) = 'july' then 7
        when substring(str, 5, len(str)) = 'september' then 9 
        when substring(str, 5, len(str)) = 'december' then 12 
    end
```

Comment: Sir @Oto Shavadze u nailed it. thats right, Thank U!

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the it to Year & Month then apply Order By clause.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (NAME VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT '2016july'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2016september'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2016december'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2016january'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017february'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017june'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017march'
```

Now do select like below

```
SELECT NAME
, CAST(SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',NAME)-1) AS INT) YEAROF
,DATEPART(MM,  SUBSTRING(NAME,PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',NAME),LEN(NAME)) +' 01 2017')  MONTHOF
FROM #TAB
ORDER BY YEAROF,MONTHOF
```

**Result:**

```
+---------------+--------+---------+
|     NAME      | YEAROF | MONTHOF |
+---------------+--------+---------+
| 2016january   |   2016 |       1 |
| 2016july      |   2016 |       7 |
| 2016september |   2016 |       9 |
| 2016december  |   2016 |      12 |
| 2017february  |   2017 |       2 |
| 2017march     |   2017 |       3 |
| 2017june      |   2017 |       6 |
+---------------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank u @Shakeer sir.